# It's wrong the solution to definite integral from Mathematica 11.3?

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I'm solving the exercise 23 from 4.8 section from "The Calculus 7th Leithold" (I use the Spanish edition "El Cálculo 7"), I write the solution in (physical) notebook, was 8*sqrt(2)/3, but when run in Mathematica:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[x - 1], {x, 1, 3}]
```

the Mathematica's solution is 4*sqrt(2)/3.

Take some time to find the problem with my solution, but I don't understand, then find the solution from the book, is the same that mine, please can tell me what happens?

Comment: $\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{2}$ is correct. One has $\int_1^3 \sqrt{x-1} \, \mathrm{d} x = \int_0^2 \sqrt{x} \, \mathrm{d} x = \left[ \frac{2}{3} x^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]^{x=2}_{x=0} = \frac{4}{3} \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Hi Henrik Schumacher, please try with [1,3] instead [0,2], and you'll see that is the double your answer. And don't forget is x-1, no x.

Comment: To elaborate on Henrik's comment, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YA9Lc.png) are the steps Wolfram|Alpha gives.

Comment: Sorry, the answer is correct, thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with the substitution `w=(x-1)^(1/2)` so that `dx=2w dw` the integral becomes
`Integrate[2 w^2, {w, 0, Sqrt[2]}]` which is `4 Sqrt[2]/3`.  I guess I agree with Mathematica on this one.  The book and its problem solutions are written by a person (or people) who may make mistakes.